# Is it possible to deploy a HTTP site to API gateway to make it HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cname

I'm new to `API gateway`,

I have a simple `wordpress site` at `http://myexamplewordpress.tech`

I want to point this URL to my API gateway invoke URL

and then assign a `cname` to API gateway invoke URL

So users can access my site using the cname `myexamplewordpress.tech` which would be `HTTPS` since its an API gateway invoke URL essentially..

Is this something that is possible ? please help me out

**Clarification**

I already have a domain name in `.tech` which is not supported in route 53 from 3rd party.. say my current site is http://myexamplewordpress.tech i want this to point to API gateway URL and assign a cname to api gateway URL which i will do from my 3rd party so my final URL should look like https://myexamplewordpress.tech i want to make it HTTPS thats what i am after in the long run

**Question**

Can i make my site `HTTPS` using API gateway only ?

Comment: In route53 you can buy/import your own domain and point it to api gateway. Not sure is this is what you are after?

Comment: I already have a domain name in .tech which is not supported in route 53 from 3rd party site.... say my current site is `http://myexamplewordpress.tech` i want this to point to API gateway URL and assign a cname to api gateway URL which i will do from my 3rd party site so my final URL should look like `https://myexamplewordpress.tech` i want to make it `HTTPS` thats what i am after in the long run :) thanks.. I will modify my problem description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make your wordpress domain HTTPS-capable using API Gateway.
You could use the new HTTP API feature for this [1] in conjunction with HTTP integrations [2] and greedy paths.
However, you will also need AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to create an SSL certificate for your custom domain name. [3]

#### Alternative

Furthermore, I would suggest to take into account AWS CloudFront as an alternative solution. I think it fits your usecase better. It supports SSL using ACM and moreover distributes your content over the continent, providing lower latency to readers. AWS provided a blog post which outlines a CloudFront solution specifically for Wordpress. [4] It slightly differs from your scenario by hosting the wordpress blog on EC2 instances within a VPC (behind an ELB). However, you could use the exact same CloudFront distribution settings with a modified origin which points at your external wordpress server instead at an S3 bucket with static assets and an ELB for dynamic content. Take a look at the blog post. It might save you some time if you want to configure things quickly.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-http.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-custom-domain-names.html
[4] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/